# Bootstrap responsive container changing position on same browser

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use the `Bootstrap` responsive width class `.container` on two pages with almost the same content, like so:

```
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
  <!-- page content here-->
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

I notice that when I navigate from one page to the other (using the `navbar`), the contents of the second page appear to start at a greater distance from the left `margin` than the first. Therefore, when transitioning to the second page, it looks like the content has moved to the right. I'm not resizing the browser. Why does this happen?

This behavior does not happen using `.container-fluid`.

Comment: is there a scroll bar on one of the pages, This would take extra space pushing the contents of the page closer.

Comment: @Toxide82 Yes! Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Hey raul - personally I don't feel there is anything here to 'fix' ... if a scroll bar is needed then it is shown ... but try adding this line of CSS to the HTML tag - overflow-y: scroll;

Comment: CSS would remove it try it on the body tag like `body {overflow:hidden;}`